# Open InputBox based on Checkbox

Tags: excel, checkbox, inputbox, vba

I'm not proficient with Excel VBA so, apologies if this sounds like an obvious question to be asked...
I'm building a model in Excel, and I'm actually trying to trigger an `inputbox` if a `checkbox` is checked.

So far I managed to do the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set Target = Range("G7")

    If Target.Value = "TRUE" Then

        Dim QtyEntry As Integer
        Dim Msg As String
        Msg = "Please insert value"
        QtyEntry = InputBox(Msg)
        ActiveSheet.Range("C7").Value = QtyEntry / 100

    End If
End Sub
```

The `target.value` `G7` is the cell linked to the `checkbox`, so it returns `TRUE` when the check is on or `FALSE` when the check is off. 
However, I've two kind of problems. The first one is that the Macro doesn't actually activate when I check the checkbox (but it does if I write "TRUE" in the target cell.

The second is that when the `inputbox` appears, it correctly places the value in cell `C7`, but then it  it keeps on asking to input values without disappearing.

Comment: Could you please edit the post with the formula that you use on cell `G7`?

Comment: There is no formula in cell G7. Since this cell is linked to the check box. When this is checked cell G7 reports "TRUE", otherwise "FALSE"

Answer (score 1):

Why not just directly take the event of the check box like so?

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Change()
    If (CheckBox1.Value) Then

        Dim QtyEntry As Integer
        Dim Msg As String
        Msg = "Please insert value"

        'errNum is used to catch if an error has happened from the inputbox entry
        Dim errNum as integer
        Err.Clear
        On error resume next 'this line tells the code to continue even if it encounters an error
        QtyEntry = InputBox(Msg)
        errNum = Err.Number
        On error goto 0 'this reset the default behavior of error handling

        Excel.Application.enableEvents = False 'this is to avoid the change of the cell "C7" calling your `Worksheet_Change` event
        'edit to include if user click cancel or nothing is entered
        If (errNum = 0) then
           ActiveSheet.Range("C7").Value = QtyEntry / 100
        End if
        Excel.Application.enableEvents = True

    End If
End Sub
```

**To be used with ActiveX `Checkbox`**

Comment: Thanks simpLE MAn, this worked great! I also added a line of code in order to reset the value to zero if the checkbox is unchecked. Just one minor bug left. Any idea on how I can avoid having an error message (and VBA editor opening) when closing the inputbox by pressing either "ok" or "cancel") without entering any value?

Comment: thanks, but not quite working, I still get error type 13 type mismatch! I'm trying to add a line of code such as            If QtyEntry = "" Then Exit Sub, but still not able to make it working.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't try my code.  Please see the edit handling this issue.